# Regex extract paragraph based on 2 regex match

Tags: python, regex

I am working on an python automation script where I want extract specific paragraph based on regex match but I am stuck on how to extract the paragraph. The following is an example showing my case:

Solution : (Consistent Pattern)

**The paragraph I want to extract (Inconsistent Pattern)**

Remote value: x (Consistent Pattern)

The following is the program that I am currently working on and it will be great if anyone could enlighten me!

```
import re
test= 'Solution\s:'
test1='Remote'
with open('<filepath>', 'r') as extract:
            
            lines=extract.readlines()

            for line in lines:
                x = re.search(test, line)
                y = re.search(test1, line)
                if x is not y:
                    f4.write(line)
                    print('good')
                else:
                    print('stop')
```

Comment: You are not using any regular expressions here. Do you mean you want to extract everything between the word 'solution' and the word 'remote'? Are these guaranteed NOT to appear in your paragraph of interest?

Comment: You need a flag variable that is True while inside the paragraph. You set it when you find the first pattern and clear it when you find the second pattern. Then output each line where the flag is True.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Hi thank you for the advice I will try to add the flag in.

Comment: @mkam Yes that is right. I want extract everything that is in between 'solution' and 'remote'. These words will not appear in the paragraph I would want to extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily done using regular expressions, for example:

```
import re

text = r"""
Solution\s:
The paragraph I
want to extract
Remote
Some useless text here
Solution\s:
Another paragraph
I want to
extract
Remote

"""
m = re.findall(r"Solution\\s:(.*?)Remote", text, re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
print(m)
```

Where `text` represents some text of interest (read in from a file, for example) from which we wish to extract all portions between the sentinel patterns `Solution\s:` and `Remote`. Here we use an IGNORECASE search so that the sentinel patterns are recognised even if spelt with different capitalization.

The above code outputs:

```
['\nThe paragraph I\nwant to extract\n', '\nAnother paragraph\nI want to\nextract\n']
```

Read the Python re library documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html for more details.